# Retrieve list of user transactions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, entity, pojo

I have been searching for a solution for the following, but was
not successful:
I have implemented a login MVC with POJO. This works well. The next step
is to add an entity class to the existing model to simply retrieve a list
of transactions of that user. The data is in the same schema as a view.

> My question: Is it recommended to add a class to the login User DAO
>   and  bean or better to separate the entities? Just POJO, no framework
>   for now.

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 and Oracle as the DBMS.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Question is extremly short and seems conceptual. maybe "programmers" site is better for such question? here question with concrete code is accepted.

Comment: Ok. Here are the components:

Comment: The UserDAO contains the sql query and check logic for the login servlet. The UserBean contains the database fields with getters and setters. The login servlet controls what happens (If user exists then show user and session on jsp page..) and finally a separate class for the database connection. What I want to achieve later is an account management system for the application users to be able to view their transactions, edit their profile and maybe print a report.